# How can the iOS 8 version of Notes be backed up locally?

Tags: icloud, backup, notes.app

I love Notes and how iCloud helps me work on the go (with my iPhone) as well as on my computer seamlessly.
But every so often, I wish I could back them all up locally in a few steps, ideally as files and with as little tampering with the system as possible.

Is this doable?

[image]

Comment: Read related question here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/111633/where-do-my-notes-written-in-the-notes-application-on-my-mac-get-saved

Comment: More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011474/backup-restore-of-notes-in-notes-app-i-e-stored-in-icloud-ios-mac-os-x-mount

Comment: And you can consider alternative solutions (for instance, Evernote) that are cross and multi platform and allow dedicated backups.

Comment: These solutions either have 0 upvotes, or are off-topic. They either mix-up Notes with Stickies, provide extremely complex solutions involving messing up the System Folder, doing some coding, and using Terminal, or suggest ... not using Notes? That can't possibly be serious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I had the answer at my fingertips, si I'll submit an answer to my own question.

An application I use for file transfers, but sometimes overlook, called [iMazing](https://imazing.com), offers native Notes conversion and backup.
There might be other apps that do this, but this is what I did and how I solved the issue in less than 30 seconds.

1-Link the iPhone with the Notes to your computer running iMazing

2-Launch iMazing

[image]

3-Select the iPhone in the list of devices, and click on the "Notes" shortcut in the left-side panel

[image]

4-A list of notes will show up. In the Finder, create a folder to receive the backed-up notes, then go back to iMazing, and Select them all [cmd+a]

[image]

5-Drag and drop them onto the Finder's folder previously created
The notes will all be converted to .txt and saved as a local file.

It's a great app, what really sucks about it is that you have to pay for it but other than that it does the task of exporting Notes quite well.

[image]

Before that, I used to use IExplorer, which worked well too.

I don't recommend using the app "Notes Explorer", unfortunately, it's a free program, so I would have loved for it to be my first answer, but when I tried it it exported Notes in a sort of HTML format with large text blocks and 
 code snippets everywhere.

There are other apps that claim to do this, at least one other which is called Syncios, which I haven't tried. If you know one that's good, feel free to recommend it in the comments section.

Also, iOS 9 now supports images in Notes, so this answer might be edited depending on what solution will work the best with this new format.

Comment: Sorry to say, this looks like an advertising of a paid product while other solutions are free. Though it's up to you which way to choose. I am not insisting.

Comment: I'm sorry if it does, such was obviously not my intent. I do not work for these people, I think their app works well most of the time. Sometimes it also crashes, but that's life I guess. This is a solution that worked for me, it's headache-free, the other ones are simply impossible... Show me a good alternative, and if it's just as simple, and free on top of it I'll update my answer! One that supports Notes with images for example...

Comment: ... and I'm the one to know the solution is satisfactory, since I'm also the OP! Not something I do often, but I just remembered how I did that a couple years ago and decided to share the answer.

Comment: @ranklord if you have downvoted this question (even if you haven't actually), please clarify what you consider is a valid "free and simple and risk-free" answer that is better than my answer. AFAIK there are lots of valid answers on here that suggest using an app to do what original OP asks. AFAIK this is a "MAC" Q & A website, Mac and Apple are themselves products/brands, so the extent to which someone "advertises" a product or software within a product-centric forum quite baffles me TBH ;).