# Can an AppleScript write to a Notes.app document?

Tags: macos, icloud, applescript, text, notes.app

I would like to write text to a "Note" (as opposed to a standard .txt or .rtf file), because Mac Notes automatically sync to an iCloud account, across devices.

(I understand that one can use various means to achieve the same effect with standard, i.e., non-proprietary, text documents, e.g., with a service like Dropbox. Notes.app is simply much more convenient.)

However, it appears that there is no way to write to a Note in AppleScript. I say this because, it doesn't seem that Notes are actually saved anywhere on the Mac as an .rtf (or similar) file. Per [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/111633/where-do-my-notes-written-in-the-notes-application-on-my-mac-get-saved) (but, note that the question was asked in 2013), I checked out the following directories:

- `~/Library/Group Containers/group.com.apple.notes/`

  - and
- `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/Notes/`

I found nothing that resembled a readable text document. I opened some of these files in TextEdit.app, and discovered that these files contain pure gobbledygook-text.

I'd imagine that I could *effectively* code an AppleScript to *"write to a Notes document,"* by triggering mouse clicks and key presses. But, I am curious if writing to a Note can be done, in a "proper" fashion.

Comment: According to the Library in the Script editor, it seems Notes is completely scriptable.  One of the properties: body (text) : the HTML content of the note .  So it appears to be scriptable using HTML markup. [Macosautomation](https://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/notes/index.html) has an older article, but the Notes app is still included in the Script Library as of macOS 10.12

Comment: Notes stores its data in an SQLite format 3 database and why it looked like gobbledygook-text in TextEdit.app when you opened the files at those locations. If you really want to look at the contents, then make a copy of the folder and open the `.storedata` file (the copy, not the original) with [Liya](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/liya/id455484422?mt=12).

Answer (score 9):

Notes is scriptable, and the dictionary can be opened with Script Editor for details.

There's also a lengthy tutorial [here](https://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/notes/02.html).

Although I've not tested it with iCloud, you should be able to set the account, and create a note in that account.

Simplifying the example on that page, and using my Exchange account, I was able to create the note using this script:

```
tell application "Notes"
  tell account "Exchange"
    make new note at folder "Notes" with properties {name:"this is a test", body:"and more text"}
  end tell
end tell
```

To get the contents of an existing note, in order to modify it:

```
tell application "Notes"
  tell account "Exchange"
    tell folder "Notes"
      get body of note "this is a test"
    end tell
  end tell
end tell
```

And, to modify the content:

```
tell application "Notes"
  tell account "Exchange"
    tell folder "Notes"
      set body of note "this is a test" to "reset the body text"
    end tell
  end tell
end tell
```

Comment: I tested this with my iCloud account and it works just fine.  Nice one, @Kent

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to edit an already-existent note? Or, do you have to create a brand new note each time?

Comment: Yep.  I modified the answer.  You'll probably want to set a variable with the original text, and make modifications before setting the body to a new value; but, that's not difficult.

Comment: I can successfully `get body of note`, but every time that I try to `set body of note`, nothing happens (even when the replacement text is proper HTML). Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, running all three of the commands above resulted in a note named "reset the body text".  The note must be named exactly as what you type in the command ("this is a test", in the example).  Setting the body once will actually change the name to "reset the body text", So, I'd check that the notes are named correctly, or maybe try to make a note without spaces in the name, etc.

Comment: [Here is a .gif](http://i.imgur.com/aC5DEBI.gifv) that shows what happens when I try to modify a Note.

Comment: Hmmm...  That might be iCloud related.  When I run with either "Exchange" or "On My Mac" account, it finishes immediately with the new text.

Comment: [Here is a .gif](http://i.imgur.com/3aPx29R.gifv) that shows what happens when I try to modify a Note in my "On My Mac" account.

Comment: I'm stumped.  I'm on Sierra 10.12.6 ; but, that shouldn't matter.  The only difference is that you have the iCloud enabled and I don't.  But, I don't see why changing "On My Mac" would cause Notes to spin out of control.

Comment: I'm on 10.11.6. I guess that it is an El Capitan bug.

Comment: How do you open an existing note? Could someone provide me with an example script?

Comment: You can open a note via the second code block above. You have to know the name of the note though.

Comment: @Kent that doesn't open the note, or even navigate to it if Notes is already running; it just retrieves the text. How do I open the note?